# Can't update the versions and the documentations to use the new version at the same time

Tags: bug, documentation, language-versions

When trying to update the "Introduction to X" page, if you modify the Versions table, you cannot use the added/modified version in the same draft to use this version, or update old references to the new one.

In the specific example, I was trying to update the [Docker page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/docker/658/introduction-to-docker), as 1.12.0 version is now out, and also wanted to update the examples with version specific parts (which change between 1.11.x and 1.12.x) in one go to refer to this new version, instead of the RC one.

Comment: Actually, when a new version is released, all topics also supporting the latest version of that series [i.e. if 5.6 is set on a topic, and that's the latest one, the new version should be added for addition of 7.0 in version history as well as 5.7. If there's also 4.4 and 4.5 is released, it should only be set on versions which have 4.5 released (and unrelated to whether 5.6, the latest, is supported)].

Comment: Can you submit a revision and then edit it using the new version?

Comment: @DavidG That's two revisions, and both need to have been approved, and while it's happening the documentations will be wrong

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I was asking what happens when you edit, save and then edit again before it has been approved. So yuo are effectively just updating your changes.

Comment: @DavidG ah, sorry. That still doesn't work. There are apparently quite a few quirks with how versions work

Comment: Yeah, didn't think it would work but thought it might be worth trying as a workaround.